# Share a folder from firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage, file-sharing

I'm currently working in a project and i want to use the firebase service. In this project i have the idea of "sharing" or giving the option to the user to download all of his data from the firebase storage.

Can any one give me any ideas? I'm using ionic framework by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use by anyway SMB protocol.

Comment: Not the kind of solution i'm looking for, but thanks for the tip!